# Is it possible to select a set of table cells for CSS styling by row class and column selector

Tags: css, html-table

I have a web app containing a reporting module. The reporting module allows the user to select which fields they want to see (by name), and builds an array of data, which a mustache-style template processor turns into a table, with 1 column for each field.

The code behind, on the server, generates the data, including total and other "special" rows. These special rows are identified by adding a css class to the row.

I have just come across a requirement for a new type of "special" row, which requires underlining a particular field. I would prefer not to have special javascript just for this type of row, so I am wondering if there is a way to identify a cell (to underline it) in a stylesheet, given just a class attached to the row(s), and an id (or other identifier) attached to the column.

I realise I could do it using nth-child, but the columns are selected by the user, so the column number wouldn't be fixed.

Just to give you an idea, I have cooked up an example (the actual code is much more complicated, and uses a lot of library functions):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each Columns}}<th id={{Id}}>{{Heading}}</th>{{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each Rows}}
        <tr class="{{Class}}>
            {{#each Data}}<td>{{Value}}</td>{{/each}}
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Typical data (number, content and order of columns varies according to user selection):

```
{
    Columns: [
        { Id: "account", Heading: "Account" },
        { Id: "subAccountValueCP", Heading: "" },
        { Id: "valueCP", Heading: "Current Period" },
        { Id: "subAccountValueLP", Heading: "" },
        { Id: "valueLP", Heading: "Prior Period" }
        ],
    Rows: [
        { Class: "heading", Data: [ "Income", "", "", "", "" ] },
        { Class: "normal", Data: [ "Consultancy", "", 5000.00, "", 4500.00 ] },
        { Class: "parent", Data: [ "Other", "", "", "", "" ] },
        { Class: "sub", Data: [ "Postage", "50.00", "", "45.00", "" ] },
        { Class: "sub", Data: [ "Packing", "50.00", "", "45.00", "" ] },
        { Class: "total", Data: [ "Other", "", 100.00, "", 90.00 ] }
    ]
}
```

Resulting table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="account">{{Heading}}</th>
            <th id="subAccountValueCP">{{Heading}}</th>
            <th id="valueCP">{{Heading}}</th>
            <th id="subAccountValueLP">{{Heading}}</th>
            <th id="calueLP">{{Heading}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="heading">
            <td>Income</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="normal">
            <td>Consultancy</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5000.00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="parent">
            <td>Other</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sub">
            <td>Postage</td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>45.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sub">
            <td>Packing</td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>45.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <td>Other</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100.00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>90.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I want to style (e.g.) the cells in rows with class `sub` and column `account` with style `padding-left: 20px;`. As the order and content of columns is entirely user-defined, the only way I know of doing it is to place a class on every cell, and select on that class. However, I wondered if there was a suitable css selector which would select cells belonging to a particular column, other than by column number, as that would do the trick much more efficiently.

Comment: can you possibly add sample code along with your question? i think this is why you still have no comments/answers yet.

Comment: I think it's not possible, only `nth-child`,  `+` and `col` are available for that, however I'm upvoting, maybe someone has any trick...

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is not possible.

The only solution was to add a class to every cell in the relevant columns, and select on `tr.rowclass td.colclass`.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `colgroup` to the table, we can style columns.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup):

> The HTML  Element (or HTML Table Column Group Element)
>   defines a group of columns within a table.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Lbyx0r77/1/)

```css
.account,
.sub {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup class="account" />
  <colgroup span="4" />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="account">{{Heading}}</th>
      <th id="subAccountValueCP">{{Heading}}</th>
      <th id="valueCP">{{Heading}}</th>
      <th id="subAccountValueLP">{{Heading}}</th>
      <th id="calueLP">{{Heading}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="heading">
      <td>Income</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normal">
      <td>Consultancy</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5000.00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4500.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
      <td>Other</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub">
      <td>Postage</td>
      <td>50.00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>45.00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub">
      <td>Packing</td>
      <td>50.00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>45.00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total">
      <td>Other</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>100.00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>90.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is useful information, but it does not help me - I do not wish to style the whole column, just particular cells within the column (depending on the class of the row).